# Linux GPIO driver only handles 2 IRQs instead of 4 that were requested

Tags: linux-device-driver, interrupt, gpio, led

I am learning to write Linux drivers with the book 'Linux-Device-Drivers 3rd Edition', and I wanted to implement a simple driver for a RaspberryPi Model 4 B to control some LEDs and buttons on a breadboard that are connected to GPIO pins.

I have 4 LEDs and 4 buttons, one for each.

This is my DTS

```dts
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

/ {
    fragment@0 {
        target-path = "/";
        __overlay__ {
            led {
                compatible = "led";
                label = "led";
                status = "okay";
                led-gpios = <&gpio 17 0>, // blue
                            <&gpio 27 0>, // red
                            <&gpio 22 0>, // green
                            <&gpio 23 0>; // yellow

                btn-gpios = <&gpio 5 1>, // blue-btn
                            <&gpio 6 1>, // red-btn
                            <&gpio 26 1>, // green-btn
                            <&gpio 24 1>; // yellow-btn
            };
        };
    };
};
```

led.h

```
#include <linux/gpio/consumer.h>

#define DATA_BUFFER_SIZE 1096

struct led_device {
    struct gpio_desc *blue, 
              *red, 
              *green, 
              *yellow, 
              *btn_0, 
              *btn_1, 
              *btn_2, 
              *btn_3;
    int irq_btn_0, 
        irq_btn_1, 
        irq_btn_2, 
        irq_btn_3;
    unsigned long btn_0_last_press_jiffies,
              btn_1_last_press_jiffies,
              btn_2_last_press_jiffies,
              btn_3_last_press_jiffies;
    struct proc_dir_entry *proc_file;
    char data_buffer[DATA_BUFFER_SIZE];
};
```

This is my driver code led.c

```c
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/mod_devicetable.h>
#include <linux/property.h>
#include <linux/platform_device.h>
#include <linux/of_device.h>
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>
#include <linux/interrupt.h>

#include <linux/jiffies.h>
extern unsigned long volatile jiffies;

#include "led.h"

MODULE_AUTHOR("******");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL v2");

static struct led_device led_dev = {
    .blue = NULL,
    .red = NULL,
    .green = NULL,
    .yellow = NULL,
    .btn_0 = NULL,
    .btn_1 = NULL,
    .btn_2 = NULL,
    .btn_3 = NULL,
    .irq_btn_0 = 0,
    .irq_btn_1 = 0,
    .irq_btn_2 = 0,
    .irq_btn_3 = 0,
    .btn_0_last_press_jiffies = 0,
    .btn_1_last_press_jiffies = 0,
    .btn_2_last_press_jiffies = 0,
    .btn_3_last_press_jiffies = 0,
    .proc_file = NULL,
};

#define LED_BLUE_INDEX 0
#define LED_RED_INDEX 1
#define LED_GREEN_INDEX 2
#define LED_YELLOW_INDEX 3

#define BTN_0_INDEX 0
#define BTN_1_INDEX 1
#define BTN_2_INDEX 2
#define BTN_3_INDEX 3

static int dt_probe(struct platform_device *pdev);
static int dt_remove(struct platform_device *pdev);

static struct of_device_id led_ids[] = {
    {
        .compatible = "led",
    }, { /* sentinel */ }
};
MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(of, led_ids);

static struct platform_driver led_driver = {
    .probe = dt_probe,
    .remove = dt_remove,
    .driver = {
        .name = "led",
        .of_match_table = led_ids,
    },
};

static irqreturn_t handle_irq(int irq, void *dev_id) {
    static unsigned long flags = 0;

    local_irq_save(flags);
    if (irq == led_dev.irq_btn_0) {
        pr_info("Button 0 was pushed\n");
    } else if (irq == led_dev.irq_btn_1) {
        pr_info("Button 1 was pushed\n");
    } else if (irq == led_dev.irq_btn_2) {
        pr_info("Button 2 was pushed\n");
    } else if (irq == led_dev.irq_btn_3) {
        pr_info("Button 3 was pushed\n");
    }
    local_irq_restore(flags);

    return IRQ_HANDLED;
};

static ssize_t led_write(struct file *filp, const char *user_buffer, size_t count, loff_t *offset) {
    int led, action;
    struct gpio_desc *gpio;

    memset(led_dev.data_buffer, 0, sizeof(led_dev.data_buffer));

    count = min(count, sizeof(led_dev.data_buffer));

    if (copy_from_user(led_dev.data_buffer, user_buffer, count)) {
        pr_err("[led] Failed to copy data from user\n");
        return -EFAULT;
    }

    if (sscanf(led_dev.data_buffer, "%d,%d", &led, &action) != 2) {
        pr_err("[led] Invalid command\n");
        return -EINVAL;
    }

    switch (led) {
        case LED_BLUE_INDEX:
            gpio = led_dev.blue;
            break;
        case LED_RED_INDEX:
            gpio = led_dev.red;
            break;
        case LED_GREEN_INDEX:
            gpio = led_dev.green;
            break;
        case LED_YELLOW_INDEX:
            gpio = led_dev.yellow;
            break;
        default:
            return count;
    }

    gpiod_set_value(gpio, !!action);
    return count;
}

static ssize_t led_read(struct file *filp, char __user *user_buffer, size_t count, loff_t *offset) {
    return 0;
};

static struct proc_ops fops = {
    .proc_write = led_write,
    .proc_read = led_read,
};

static int setup_leds_gpios(struct device *dev) {
    int ret = 0;

    led_dev.blue = gpiod_get_index(dev, "led", LED_BLUE_INDEX, GPIOD_OUT_LOW);
    if (IS_ERR(led_dev.blue)) {
        pr_err("[led] Failed to setup blue LED\n");
        return PTR_ERR(led_dev.blue);
    }

    led_dev.red = gpiod_get_index(dev, "led", LED_RED_INDEX, GPIOD_OUT_LOW);
    if (IS_ERR(led_dev.red)) {
        pr_err("[led] Failed to setup red LED\n");
        ret = PTR_ERR(led_dev.red);
        goto error_red;
    }

    led_dev.green = gpiod_get_index(dev, "led", LED_GREEN_INDEX, GPIOD_OUT_LOW);
    if (IS_ERR(led_dev.green)) {
        pr_err("[led] Failed to setup green LED\n");
        ret = PTR_ERR(led_dev.green);
        goto error_green;
    }

    led_dev.yellow = gpiod_get_index(dev, "led", LED_YELLOW_INDEX, GPIOD_OUT_LOW);
    if (IS_ERR(led_dev.yellow) {
        pr_err("[led] Failed to setup yellow LED\n");
        ret = PTR_ERR(led_dev.yellow);
        goto error_yellow;
    }

    return ret; 

error_yellow:
    gpiod_put(led_dev.green);
error_green:
    gpiod_put(led_dev.red);
error_red:
    gpiod_put(led_dev.blue);
    return ret;
};

static int setup_btns_gpios(struct device *dev) {
    int ret = 0;

    led_dev.btn_0 = gpiod_get_index(dev, "btn", BTN_0_INDEX, GPIOD_IN);
    if (IS_ERR(led_dev.btn_0)) {
        pr_err("[led] Failed to setup button 0\n");
        return PTR_ERR(led_dev.btn_0);
    }

    led_dev.btn_1 = gpiod_get_index(dev, "btn", BTN_1_INDEX, GPIOD_IN);
    if (IS_ERR(led_dev.btn_1)) {
        printk("[led] Failed to setup button 1\n");
        ret = PTR_ERR(led_dev.btn_1);
        goto error_btn_1;
    }

    led_dev.btn_2 = gpiod_get_index(dev, "btn", BTN_2_INDEX, GPIOD_IN);
    if (IS_ERR(led_dev.btn_2)) {
        printk("[led] Failed to setup button 2\n");
        ret = PTR_ERR(led_dev.btn_2);
        goto error_btn_2;
    }

    led_dev.btn_3 = gpiod_get_index(dev, "btn", BTN_3_INDEX, GPIOD_IN);
    if (IS_ERR(led_dev.btn_3)) {
        printk("[led] Failed to setup button 3\n");
        ret = PTR_ERR(led_dev.btn_3);
        goto error_btn_3;
    }

    return ret;

error_btn_3:
    gpiod_put(led_dev.btn_2);
error_btn_2:
    gpiod_put(led_dev.btn_1);
error_btn_1:
    gpiod_put(led_dev.btn_0);
    return ret;
};

static int setup_btns_irqs(void) {
    int ret = 0;

    led_dev.irq_btn_0 = gpiod_to_irq(led_dev.btn_0);
    ret = request_irq(led_dev.irq_btn_0, 
                      handle_irq,
                      IRQF_TRIGGER_FALLING,
                      "led-btn-0", 
                      NULL);
    if (ret) {
        pr_err("[led] Failed to register IRQ for button 0\n");
        return ret;
    }

    led_dev.irq_btn_1 = gpiod_to_irq(led_dev.btn_1);
    ret = request_irq(led_dev.irq_btn_1, 
                      handle_irq,
                      IRQF_TRIGGER_FALLING,
                      "led-btn-1", 
                      NULL);
    if (ret) {
        pr_err("[led] Failed to register IRQ for button 1\n");
        goto btn_1_irq_error;
    }

    led_dev.irq_btn_2 = gpiod_to_irq(led_dev.btn_2);
    ret = request_irq(led_dev.irq_btn_2, 
                      handle_irq,
                      IRQF_TRIGGER_FALLING,
                      "led-btn-2", 
                      NULL);
    if (ret) {
        pr_err("[led] Failed to register IRQ for button 2\n");
        goto btn_2_irq_error;
    }

    led_dev.irq_btn_3 = gpiod_to_irq(led_dev.btn_3);
    ret = request_irq(led_dev.irq_btn_3, 
                      handle_irq,
                      IRQF_TRIGGER_FALLING,
                      "led-btn-3", 
                      NULL);
    if (ret) {
        pr_err("[led] Failed to register IRQ for button 3\n");
        goto btn_3_irq_error;
    }

    return ret;

btn_3_irq_error:
    free_irq(led_dev.irq_btn_2, NULL);
btn_2_irq_error:
    free_irq(led_dev.irq_btn_1, NULL);
btn_1_irq_error:
    free_irq(led_dev.irq_btn_0, NULL);
    return ret;
};

static void free_btns_gpios(void) {
    if (led_dev.btn_0) {
             gpiod_put(led_dev.btn_0);
        led_dev.btn_0 = NULL;
    }

    if (led_dev.btn_1) {
        gpiod_put(led_dev.btn_1);
        led_dev.btn_1 = NULL;
    }

    if (led_dev.btn_2) {
        gpiod_put(led_dev.btn_2);
        led_dev.btn_2 = NULL;
    }

    if (led_dev.btn_3) {
        gpiod_put(led_dev.btn_3);
        led_dev.btn_3 = NULL;
    }
};

static void free_leds_gpios(void) {
    if (led_dev.blue) {
        gpiod_put(led_dev.blue);
        led_dev.blue = NULL;
    }

    if (led_dev.red) {
        gpiod_put(led_dev.red);
        led_dev.red = NULL;
    }

    if (led_dev.green) {
        gpiod_put(led_dev.green);
        led_dev.green = NULL;
    }

    if (led_dev.yellow) {
        gpiod_put(led_dev.yellow);
        led_dev.yellow = NULL;
    }
};

static void free_btns_irqs(void) {
    if (led_dev.irq_btn_0) {
        free_irq(led_dev.irq_btn_0, NULL);
        led_dev.irq_btn_0 = 0;
    }

    if (led_dev.irq_btn_1) {
        free_irq(led_dev.irq_btn_1, NULL);
        led_dev.irq_btn_1 = 0;
    }

    if (led_dev.irq_btn_2) {
        free_irq(led_dev.irq_btn_2, NULL);
        led_dev.irq_btn_2 = 0;
    }

    if (led_dev.irq_btn_3) {
        free_irq(led_dev.irq_btn_3, NULL);
        led_dev.irq_btn_3 = 0;
    }
};

static int dt_probe(struct platform_device *pdev) {
    struct device *dev = &pdev->dev;
    int ret = 0;
    
    if ((ret = setup_leds_gpios(dev))) {
        return ret;
    }

    if ((ret = setup_btns_gpios(dev))) {
        goto error_btns;
    }

    if ((ret = setup_btns_irqs())) {
        goto error_btn_irqs;
    }
    
    led_dev.proc_file = proc_create("led", 0666, NULL, &fops);
    if (led_dev.proc_file == NULL) {
        pr_err("[led] Failed to create /proc/led\n");
        ret = -ENOMEM;
        goto error_proc_file;
    }

    pr_info("[led] Successfully setup GPIO driver\n");

    return ret;

error_proc_file:
    free_btns_irqs();
error_btn_irqs:
    free_btns_gpios();
error_btns:
    free_leds_gpios();

    return ret;
}

static int dt_remove(struct platform_device *pdev) {
    pr_info("[led] Removing device\n");

    free_btns_irqs();
    free_btns_gpios();
    free_leds_gpios();
    proc_remove(led_dev.proc_file);

    return 0;
}

static int __init led_init(void) {
    pr_info("[led] Loading LED driver\n");
    if (platform_driver_register(&led_driver)) {
        pr_err("[led] Failed to register driver\n");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
};

static void __exit led_cleanup(void) {
    pr_info("[led] Cleaning up LED driver\n");
    platform_driver_unregister(&led_driver);
};

module_init(led_init);
module_exit(led_cleanup);
```

All of the buttons' circuits are wired - GPIO IN pin -> button -> GND. I followed the instructions on the [RaspberryPi website](https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/button-switch-scratch-pi/1) for connecting the buttons.

My problem is when I load my module and press the buttons, only the IRQs of `btn_0` and `btn_1` run.

This is the output of `dmesg` after pressing all of the buttons one after the other in order

```
[led] Successfully setup GPIO driver
Button 0 was pushed
Button 1 was pushed
```

This is the content of `/proc/interrupts`

```
 69:          1          0          0          0  pinctrl-bcm2835   5 Edge      led-btn-0
 70:          1          0          0          0  pinctrl-bcm2835   6 Edge      led-btn-1
 71:          0          0          0          0  pinctrl-bcm2835  26 Edge      led-btn-2
 72:          0          0          0          0  pinctrl-bcm2835  24 Edge      led-btn-3
```

I can't seem to understand why the IRQs for `btn_2` and `btn_3` aren't triggering no matter how many times I press the buttons.

Edit:

From what I read online, it seems that since my pins are connected to GND, I need to set a pull-up resistor so that when the circuit is open, the pin will read HIGH, I'm just not sure on how to do that from within the kernel module.

Comment: Have you checked the pin control and pin mixing? (Pull bias and GPIO function to be selected)

Comment: @0andriy I must confess I’m not sure how to check those, or what they mean

Comment: @0andriy I looked online and learned a little about the push/pull bias and function, but I’m still not sure how to configure them

Comment: @0andriy Take a look at my edit, do you think that could be the issue?

Comment: Pretty much. But you need to do this in the Device Tree or ACPI description. This is part of pin control.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As @0andiry mentions in their comments, the issue really was with the pull bias. Turns out the pull bias for GPIO pins 24 and 26 is low. I made sure of that with the command

```bash
sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/gpio
```

The output shows that the pull bias is low, as indicated by the `lo` part

```bash
gpio-24  (GPIO24              |btn                 ) in  lo IRQ ACTIVE LOW
gpio-26  (GPIO24              |btn                 ) in  lo IRQ ACTIVE LOW
```

To fix that, I changed the pull bias to high in my device tree file in the `&gpio` node. This is the working DTS

```
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

/ {
    compatible = "brcm,bcm2835", "brcm,bcm2708", "brcm,bcm2709", "brcm,bcm2710", "brcm,bcm2711";
    fragment@0 {
        target = <&gpio>;
        __overlay__ {
            btn_pins: btn_pins {
                brcm,pins = <5 6 26 24>; // gpio no.
                brcm,function = <0>;     // 0:in, 1:out
                brcm,pull = <2>;         // 2:up 1:down 0:none
            };
        };
    };
    fragment@1 {
        target-path = "/";
        __overlay__ {
            led {
                compatible = "led";
                label = "led";
                status = "okay";
                pinctrl-0 = <&btn_pins>;
                pinctrl-names = "default";
                led-gpios = <&gpio 17 0>, // led-0
                            <&gpio 27 0>, // led-1
                            <&gpio 22 0>, // led-2
                            <&gpio 23 0>; // led-3

                btn-gpios = <&gpio 5 1>,  // btn-0
                            <&gpio 6 1>,  // btn-1
                            <&gpio 26 1>, // btn-2
                            <&gpio 24 1>; // btn-3
            };
        };
    };
};
```

Checking `/sys/kernel/debug/gpio` after rebuilding my driver and DTS and loading them, it shows the following

```bash
gpio-24  (GPIO24              |btn                 ) in  hi IRQ ACTIVE LOW
gpio-26  (GPIO24              |btn                 ) in  hi IRQ ACTIVE LOW
```

Comment: You should not answer your own questions

Comment: Um... Why not? I did solve my problem and posted a solution incase anyone ever runs into the same issue.

Comment: I thought it was not OK to accept answers to your own questions, but checked again and is not against the rules. Of course you don't gain any points for that. My bad.

Comment: @DraženGrašovec No problem. I just answered it to help anyone who perhaps runs into the same issue as me in the future.